# Are commas needed after "yesterday" and "today" in these sentences (introductory clauses)

Tags: clauses

Yesterday post call, we worked on small fixes and completing user interactions.

Today once we complete those final touches, we will conduct a design review and polish the build to match the designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently written the answer is yes to a comma after "Yesterday" and "Today".

The reason is a complete sentence can be construed minus the verbiage immediately following both words. Ex: Yesterday we worked on small fixes and completing user interactions. Ex: Today we will conduct a design review and polish the build to match the designs.

To me, a better way of writing the first sentence, is as follows: After yesterday's call we worked on small fixes and completing user interactions.